# File Format Detection in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have a very large number of blobs in Azure that we would like to add to an Azure Search index. These blobs have a variety of formats (PDF, DOC, RTF, etc), but none of them have file extensions.

Because of this, Azure Search balks during indexing as it appears to only use the file extension to do file format detection. We get the following error, and since all of our files have these "invalid" extensions, it would happen regardless of any threshold set for indexing errors:

> Import configuration failed, error creating Indexer: "Error with data
>   source: Document
>   'https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/folder/filename.00001' has
>   unsupported content type 'unsupported'. To index only the blob
>   metadata and ignore its content, set the 'dataToExtract' indexer
>   configuration property to 'storageMetadata'. See
>   https://aka.ms/azsearchblobdatatoextract.  To ignore this error and
>   continue indexing blobs with unsupported content types, set the
>   'failOnUnsupportedContentType' switch in indexer configuration to
>   false. For more information, see
>   https://aka.ms/blob-indexer-parameters-for-extraction.  Please adjust
>   your data source definition in order to proceed."

Are there any ways to have Azure Search either do file content based file detection, or at least use meta data on the blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search already does content based content type detection, but some blobs are problematic. These problematic blobs can be skipped over during indexer operation (with a warning so you know what happened), but if such a blob is encountered during indexer *creation*, the creation fails with the error you encountered.

If you remove (or skip using the blob metadata) the blob in question, do most of your other blobs work as expected? I suspect Azure Search team would be interested in taking a look at the problematic blob if it would be possible for you to share it.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. It just always failed on the first blob. I will configure it to continue on error and see how many files it's able to index. Thank you!

Comment: That indicates your first blob might be problematic. If you care about indexing as many documents as possible, I recommend setting the `failOnUnsupportedContentType` switch to false, as well as `maxFailedItems` to -1, to indicate that failure to index file items are permissible.

Comment: Unfortunately, when i disable FfailOnUnsupportedContentType, Azure Search propertly indexes 600+ documents, but only does so on the meta data. For every document, including some that are PDF, RTF, images, etc, I get ""Document has unsupported content type 'unsupported'. Blob metadata was indexed, but content extraction was skipped.". I'm going to rename some of these to their correct file extensions and see if this "solves" the issue.

Comment: Turns out the root problem was that the documents I was trying to index were all encrypted using the blob storage API rather than using TDE. This, obviously, preventing indexing. Once I tried this on a collection of non-encrypted documents, regardless of file extension, it worked great.